# MySQL - Compare 2 lines with specific attribute

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

First of all, sorry for this title, I tried my best to describe it.

I'm trying to override the WordPress' function wc_get_product_ids_on_sale() because one of my plugin is creating _sale_price even if it's the same than price.

I'd to know, how can I get only post_id which has :

- _sale_price different from _price
- _sale_price not empty

I only know how to get empty...

```html
SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE meta_key = '_sale_price'
AND meta_value <> ''
```

Do you have any ideas ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use pivoting to extract and then compare the meta values:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM wp_postmeta
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_sale_price' THEN meta_value END) = '' AND
    MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_price' THEN meta_value END) <> '';
```

This answer assumes that the `meta_value` column is text, and not a number.  If the column be numeric, then you will have to clarify what empty means here.

If you are new to the concept of pivot queries, then I refer you to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't understand how those having compare _sale_price to _price. Can you explain me ?

Comment: @Destunk If you are asking for a full explanation of this, then it really might be too broad for a single question here.  Check the link above to see how to write a pivot query in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the link, the problem was that I didn't know how to find this information on the web